# Printing memory accesses in GDB

Tags: memory, gcc, gdb, trace

I am new to gdb. I want to print the memory addresses used with the actual sequence during execution of a c program. Let’s explain my question with an example. Let’s assume that we have the following c code with two functions main() and test(). I know that, inside gdb, I can use "disassemble main" to disassemble main() function, or "disassemble test" to disassemble test() function separately. My question is, how can I disassemble these two functions as a single code; so that, I can see all the memory addresses used during execution and their sequence of accesses? To be specific, as main() is calling test() and test() is also calling itself multiple times, I want to see something like example 2. I am also wandering, the addresses shown in gdb disassembler, are they virtual or physical memory addresses? Any help or guidance will be appreciated.

Example 1:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int test(int q)
{
    if(q<16)
    test(q+5);

    return q;
}

void main()
{
    unsigned int a=5;
    unsigned int b=5;
    unsigned int c=5;

    test(a);
}
```

Example 2:

```
<Memory Address> <assembly instruction> <c instructions>

0x12546a    mov //for unsigned int a=5;
0x12546b    mov //for unsigned int b=5;
0x12546c    mov //for unsigned int c=5;    
0x12546d    jmp //for test(q=a=5);
0x12546e    cmpl //for if(q<16)
0x12546f    jmp //for test(q+5);
0x12546d    jmp //for test(q=10);
0x12546e    cmpl //for if(q<16)
0x12546f    jmp //for test(q+5);
0x12547a    jmp //for test(q=15);
0x12547b    cmpl //for if(q<16)
0x12547c    jmp //for test(q+5);
0x12547d    jmp //for test(q=20);
0x12547e    cmpl //for if(q<16)
0x12547f    jmp //return q);
0x12548a    jmp //return q);
0x12548b    jmp //return q);
0x12548c    jmp //return q);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's really no pretty way to do this. You're just going to have to step through the code:

```
(gdb) stepi
(gdb) x/i $pc
(gdb) info registers
(gdb) stepi
(gdb) x/i $pc
(gdb) info registers
.....
```

You could script that up so that it does it quickly and dumps the data to a file, but that's about all.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you may have more luck with valgrind. If there's no existing tool to do so, it is possible to add your own instrumentation to report memory accesses (and not only that), or alter an existing one.

E.g. see http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/lk-manual.html

--trace-mem= [default: no]

When enabled, Lackey prints the size and address of almost every memory access made by the program.